# How can I assign a sharing rule to a specific user only

Tags: sharing

How can I assign a sharing rule to a specific user only. Bec when I click on sharing rule of a lead object I can view that

> select the users to be shared

I only want to assign to a single user only. Please guide me. Permission set is one solution. Is there any other way. Please guide me.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a "Public Group" containing only that specific user and then use that group (that corresponds to that specific user) when you add "Sharing Rules" in "Sharing Settings".

Comment: yes that can be done but I just want to know is possible to assign directly to a user without assigning to any profile role group etc. As @mohith has mentioned some way but not able to do achieve it.

Comment: @Anu OK. Creating a group is trivial but if that doesn't work for you for some reason hopefully Mohith will give you some more help.

Answer (score 1):

Create a criteria based sharing rule with a boolean flag on user .Make sure to check this boolean only for user you want your sharing rule to run.

Comment: can you please show any demo or give steeps not able tu understand boolean flag on user.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using based on criteria rule type and filtering the data by the ownerId field in the rule.
[image]